# Failed to open a connection to the database

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have used Visual Studio 2008 for crystal report development and try to connect SQL database (SQL server 2008-R2) in .xsd file, but I have failed. I have also try to fixed issue by installing service pack of visual studio 2008, but still issue is not resolve.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986

### Error Message:

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Failed to open a connection to the database

This server version is not supported.  Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported.

Please give your suggestion

Thank You in advance